# Как переопределить accentColor у Switch

Tags: android, style

Никак не получается переделать accent цвет для конкретного switch.

```
<Switch
      android:id="@+id/switch1"
      style="@style/exesSwitch"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
      android:layout_weight="80"
      android:checked="true"
                    />
```

На одном из форумов нашел во такое решение, но мне как-то не помогло.

```
<style name="exesSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#46bdbf</item>

    <!-- inactive thumb color -->
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#f1f1f1 </item>

    <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
    <item name="android:colorForeground">#42221f1f</item>

</style>
```

так же пробовал создавать стиль с единственным параметром:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPAccent</item>
```

При всех попытках switch  все также использует основной colorAccent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что не правильно подключал стиль. Предыдущий вариант работал в api<20 
Нужно было вот так

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
 android:id="@+id/switch1"
 android:theme="@style/exesSwitch"
 ...
```